# Get list element with JQuery according to its value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Assume I have the following list:

```
    <ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
        <li><a href="#">RU</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">RO</a></li>
    </ul>
```

With JQuery, I want to select the list element which has the value `RU`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative solution in one line ;)

```js
var ru = $("ul li a:contains('RU')").text();

// Demonstration purposes only

$('.tron').text(ru);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
        <li><a href="#">RU</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">RO</a></li>
    </ul>

<!-- Demonstration purposes only -->
<h1 class="tron"></h1>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try something like:

```
$(".pagination li a").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "RU";
});
```

Answer (score 2):

select all list items and use the [jQuery .filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to filter elements with the needed text:

```js
$(function(){
    $(".pagination li").filter(function(){
        return $(this).text()=="RU";
    }).css({
        "border":"2px solid red"
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
        <li><a href="#">RU</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">RO</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify `value` attribute in each `li` tag
As in your example
`<li value="RU"><a href="#">RU</a></li>
<li value="RO"><a href="#">RO</a></li>` after that to access value of `li` tag use this
`$(li).val();`

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can achieve this `$('li').eq(0).text() == 'RU';` simple as that but you need to navigate more often to jquery site for info on this kind of stuff.